# least square fitting to complex numbers in python with errors

Tags: python, complex-numbers, least-squares

Apologies here is the code.
I am trying to fit a Bessel function to some 2D data, the Bessel function is complex. However when I fit the data I always end up with an array error, which I cannot sort ( I am new to python). In the end the code would ideally give me the error to account for the scatter of the imported data.

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
from scitools.std import *
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.special
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit



xdata=np.array([7.6,22.6,47.6,97.6,147.6,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200,1300])
ydata=np.array([1.19E-05,1.05E-05,1.06E-05,9.92E-06,9.85E-06,9.88E-06,9.45E-06,9.77E-06,9.59E-06,1.09E-05,1.22E-05,1.39E-05,1.78E-05,2.04E-05,2.61E-05,3.17E-05,3.86E-05])





b = 1.63854196884e+39
def func(x,p1,p2):
    return p2*(sqrt((scipy.special.jn(1,(1j*sqrt((8*b*p1**3*(x/10000))))))/(1j*sqrt((2*b*p1**3*(x/10000))))))


popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata,p0=(1.0,0.2))
```

This code is meant to show the rough problem, but in the end I want the value of p1 and p2 plus the error.

the error I get back is this, ( I know its basic but I keep messing up )

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

### TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type

error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    173             else:
    174                 filename = fname
--> 175             **builtin**.execfile(filename, *where)

/Users/sean/Cardiff/DTO/paulsen/carley report/crap.py in ()
     21 
     22 
---> 23 popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata,p0=(1.0,0.2))
     24 
     25

/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, **kw)
    553     # Remove full_output from kw, otherwise we're passing it in twice.

```
554     return_full = kw.pop('full_output', False)
```

--> 555     res = leastsq(func, p0, args=args, full_output=1, **kw)
    556     (popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier) = res
    557

/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    377             maxfev = 200*(n + 1)
    378         retval = _minpack._lmdif(func, x0, args, full_output, ftol, xtol,
--> 379                                  gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    380     else:
    381         if col_deriv:

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: What is array error that you're getting?

Comment: You need to show a sample of your data and the error message, if you really want someone to help you...